# Cytoscape for undirected graphs

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js

[Cytoscape.js](http://[cytoscape.js]) claims to support both directed and undirected graphs. Yet, I see only one way to add an edge:

```
cy.add(kind:"edge", source:node, target: node)
```

The signature says that there is a difference between ends. The implications are more serious, as they seem to me the Noob. In my graph model, I support bidirectional connections. That is, every node maintains a set of references to connected counterparts. That is, if a is connected to `b` then `b` exists withing `a` node and vice-versa. How do I draw such graph? Should I add two edges (a->b) and b->a or only one of them if I do not draw the edge arrows? What is supposd pattern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph is undirected, then it doesn't matter which node is specified as `source` and which node is specified as `target`.

You can show no arrows or arrows in both directions using your [stylesheet](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style).

Comment: if you use stylesheet, you will have to specify those edges that are one direction and those that are bidirecional.